# Cannot edit new locale in Codename One IntelliJ plugin

Tags: intellij-idea, codenameone

I am using IntelliJ for Codename One development. I am trying to add a new locale, so the steps I do are the following:
1. Double click the theme.res
2. Click on Localization -> Add Resource Bundle
3. Add a new locale, say "de"
4. Double click on some row, or click "Edit text". Now I expect to be able to write in a value for the new locale, but nothing happens.

My expectations are based on [this video](https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---localizetranslate-my-application-apply-i18nl10n-internationalizationlocalization-to-my-app.html) and on the developer guide. Am I missing something or this is a bug in the IntelliJ plugin?

Comment: For now I am using theme.xml, but it is slightly annoying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a regression with the first 5 default entries. If you add a new entry into the designer tool it should work.

The problem is that the new entries are null instead of blank strings and one of our recent fixes failed to account to that. If you set them to a non-null value thru the XML and then try to edit again this should work as expected in the GUI.

We'll fix this in the next plugin update within 3-4 weeks (sometime during September 2016). Since the designer is part of the tooling and not the API it isn't updated every week. The fix is already in git.

Comment: Should I open an issue for that in the github issue tracker?

Comment: No need. We already fixed it. We just released a plugin last week and we don't release plugin updates as frequently as we do library updates.